# node.js template to convert JSON objects

Tags: json, template-engine

I would like to use some expression language in JSON objects. Let's say I have a "template" like:

```
jsonTemplate = {
    title:"Title: '#{title}',
    header: "Created by #{meta.author} at #{meta.createdAt}"
}
```

and the actual data as follows:

```
data = {
    title: "Some title",
    content:"bla...",
    meta: {createdAt:new Date(), author:"me"}
}
```

I would like to do something similar to

```
parser.render(jsonTemplate, data);
```

to return

```
{
    title:"Title: 'Some title'",
    header: "Created by me at 2012-05-10 10:00:00"
}
```

All the template engines focus on html generation, but the result of the "render" step should be a json object.

Is there any engine which allows this?

If not, I would create the json object myself and apply an existing engine to the single attributes. Would you recommend an engine for this?

Ideally this should be available as node.js module or common.js.